# How to stop the first function when the second function is called?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have called the first "a1" function and it's starts running in the loop and when I called the second "a2" function, the  first "a1" function supposed to stop and second function has to start running, but the two functions are running in parallel. I need to stop the first function when the second function is called.

```
def a1(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        add = request.POST['addition']
        while True:
            add = add + 1
            print(add)
            time.sleep(2)
    return render(request, blog/finished.html)
        
def a2(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        check = request.POST['checking']
        while True:
            print(check)
            print("second function: ",check)
            time.sleep(2)        
    return render(request, blog/finished.html)
```

Comment: Using `while True` with `time.sleep` will not return anything in your request handler functions. I guess this is why you asked the question. I'd recommend reading Django, queue management tools and celery (or similar) solutions to handle your situation in a more elaborate way. They can help you to improve state management and business logic like this one.

Comment: When a client sends a HTTP request, it usually expects to receive a response shortly after. If the durations involved are more than a few seconds, you should look at asynchronous solutions. Most browsers will show a timeout error if they don't get a response after a while. Also, well configured web servers will abort Django processes that take too long.

Answer (score 1):

The two requests are running independently hence they cannot communicate with each other directly.  You would need to have some means of tracking the state of request a1.  In Django, you can do this with a database table which could record the state of a1 (e.g. running).  Then a2 can update this state to 'stopped', which a1 would have to poll to find out whether it should stop running or not.

I've ignored why you would want to do this because deliberately putting requests into a loop with sleeps will tie up resources on the webserver and could lead to performance issues.

Comment: Could you please help me on setting up the database table?

Comment: the best place to start is [the django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: Using a redis-like database can be more suitable in this case. At least it can be a second option.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Django-channels.

This is a good tutorial and documentation: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

This way multiple users/pages can communicate to the same process and receive data from that process without a lot of pain on the webserver.

This uses Redis, so be prepared for that